# Receiving LiveData callbacks for a paused activity

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I have 2 activities A and B. They both listen to a globally scoped Livedata that lives outside these 2 activities. When I navigate to activity B from activity A these are the lifecycle events reported.

1. A -> paused
2. B -> created
3. B -> started
4. B -> resumed
5. A -> stopped

My issue is that mutating the LiveData in any of the first 4 steps results in Activity A still receiving LiveData callbacks even though the user is already on activity B.

I could remove the observer in Activity A when onPause is called but I thought the whole idea of LiveDatas was that I don't have to remove observers.

**Question: What are my options for not receiving callbacks in activity A once the user leaves the activity?**

Activity A

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Global.liveData.observe(this, Observer {
        doUiWork()
    })
 }
```

Comment: Where did you read you dont have to remove observers?

Comment: As LiveDatas are lifecycle aware and observers don't receive callbacks when the lifecycle owner is not active I assumed the observer doesn't have to be removed. My issue is that activity A is still considered active even though I'm already on activity B. Also don't remember seeing architectures that call remove observer.

Comment: can you please share the `observe` code used in Activity A?

Comment: @CSmith it's implemented like this.